# C malloc error freeing struct

Tags: c, memory-management, struct, malloc, free

I've just re-start learning C, but i'm really confused with some memory management details.
I'm getting

> pointer being freed was not allocated ... Abort trap

for the code below. Do i **really** need 1 free per malloc? Why my code is wrong?

Thanks!

```
#define N 9

typedef struct
{
  int MAX_LIST_SIZE;
  int length;
  int *ini;
}List;

/* allocates new List and its data */
List *newList(int size)
{
    List *list = malloc(sizeof(List));
    list->MAX_LIST_SIZE = size;
    list->length = 0;
    list->ini = malloc(sizeof(int) * size);

    return list;
}

/* add some value to the list */
void addList(List *list, int val)
{
    if (list->length < list->MAX_LIST_SIZE)
        list->ini[list->length++] = val;
    else
        fprintf(stderr, "Error: add(): List is full.\n");
}

/* get an array of N*N lists malloc-ed Lists */
List *gridList()
{
    int i, j;
    List *cells = malloc(sizeof(List) * N * N);

    for (i = 0; i < N * N; i++)
    {
      /* malloc is called inside NewList()*/
      cells[i] = *newList(N);
      for (j = 0; j < N; j++)
          addList(&cells[i], j + 1);
    }

    return cells;
}


/* inside main */
List *cells = gridList();

/* use cells ... */

/* free */
for (i = 0; i < N * N;  i++)
{
    free(cells[i].ini);
    /* line below causes CRASH */
    free(&cells[i]);
}
```

Comment: 1) The code doesn't need to be 'complete' 2)? 3)I got Java.

Comment: C is a fine language.  However @Beta's point about small, complete, compilable example is excellent.  You're more likely to get an answer if you follow his advice.

Comment: @Beta: Points 1 and 2 are very good. As for point 3, this is hardly the place for a language war.

Comment: As i said, the code is trivial for a 'C guy', that's why i didn't bother to show the whole code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do :

```
cells[i] = *newList(N);
```

which sets each element in `cells` to a copy of the list dynamically allocated by `newList`. So `newList` dynamically allocates a list, then you take the pointer to that dynamically allocated `List`, dereference it, and copy it into `cells[i]`. So then later on when you go to `free()` each element:

```
free(&cells[i]);
```

It doesn't work because each element in `cells[i]` is a `List`, not a `List *` (list pointer) allocated by `malloc()`.

So you have two options. One (bad one) is to just remove that last `free()` line since there's nothing to free. However, this just covers up a larger problem which is that you now have memory leaks because you can't go back and free the dynamically allocated `List`s created with `newList()`.

Instead it's likely you want to have an array of pointers to the lists, which you can do by changing it to:

```
List **cells = malloc(sizeof(List*) * N * N);
```

so that `cells[i]` refers to a `List *`. `newList()` returns such a pointer, so you would change that line to:

```
cells[i] = newList(N);
```

similarly, `addList()` takes such a pointer, so you'd simply change that line to:

```
addList(cells[i], j + 1);
```

since `&cells[i]` would pass it the address of the pointer, which is not what you want.

Finally, change the free statements to:

```
free(cells[i]->ini); // ->init because cells[i] is now a pointer to a List, List *
free(cells[i]);
```

Comment: This 'copy' thing i didn't get. The function newPoint() returns a List* that points to 'p1'. You're saying &cells[i] didn't point to 'p1' if i do cells[i] = *newPoint()?

Comment: `newList()` indeed returns a `List *` that points to the `malloc()`'ed `List` (I don't know what you mean by `p1`). When you then do `cells[i] = *newList()`, the asterisk in `*newList()` part dereferences that pointer, so you get the actual `List`, not a pointer. Since `cells[i]` refers to a `List`, it copies the `List` on the right side (`*newList()`) into the `List` on the left (`cells[i]`). It's copied because that's how things are done in C. In response to your comment, if you do `cells[i] = *newList()`, `cells[i]` doesn't point to anything, it _is_ a `List` (copy of the one returned).

Comment: Think of it like if you had `malloc()`ed an integer. `int *someInt = malloc(sizeof(int));`. Here, `someInt` is a pointer to the `malloc()`ed integer, not the integer itself. So you can do `int *aPointer = someInt`. However, in your case, `cells[i]` didn't hold a pointer to a `List` (`List *`), but rather, a `List` itself, so you were dereferencing it first. So in this example, `int aCopy = *someInt;`.

Comment: In the new updated code, `cells[i]` "contains" a pointer to a `List`, right? `List *`. So when you do `cells[i] = newList()`, `cells[i]` now contains the pointer to the object allocated by `newList()`. That's the important thing, `cells[i]` is not a `List` object, it's a _pointer_ to a `List` object. So if you take the address of that, you're getting the address of the `List` pointer. What you want is the address of the `List` that pointer (`cells[i]`) points to, which quite simply is attainable just like that: `cells[i]`.

Comment: It might help to treat a list pointer `List *` as a completely different type, imagine it being called `ListPtr`. `newList()` returns a `ListPtr`, not a `List`. You can _get_ the `List` that `ListPtr` points to by doing `*someListPtr`. Similarly, `cells[i]` can only hold a `ListPtr`, not a `List`. So it's fine to do `cells[i] = newList()` because `newList()` returns a `ListPtr`. If you later want the address of the `List` that a `ListPtr` points to, you simply use it by its name: `cells[i]` in this case would return the address of the `List` that the `ListPtr` stored in that element points to.

Comment: Yes yes...i understand the new code 100%. What really bugs me is why &cells[i] (an address) is not equal to the address that is returned when i call newPoint(). That's the tricky detail that every book should explain.

Comment: @Fernando Yeah it can be tricky. See my latest comment, hopefully that helps.

Comment: So continuing from the `ListPtr` example: Remember, `cells` contains `ListPtrs` _not_ `Lists`. So if you do `&cells[i]` you are getting the address of the `ListPtr` stored at `i`, _not_ the address of the `List` that the `ListPtr` points to. If you want the address that the `ListPtr` points to, you simply do `cells[i]`. If you want the `List` that the `ListPtr` points to, you simply do `*cells[i]`.

Comment: Yes, the new code is fine. In my previous code the returned 'pointer' to the List (inside newList()) is lost (or something like that), so &cell[i] will not work later. That's what i get, thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you are allocating an array of lists, copying the full contents of your lists into the array elements, and then trying to free them.  The original allocated List records are a memory leak, and the free calls are indeed trying to free memory that was not malloc'ed (or more exactly were malloc'ed in a single big block).

You want an array of pointers to pointers to hold your lists:

```
/* get an array of N*N lists malloc-ed Lists */
List **gridList()
{
    int i, j;
    // VV note change here
    List **cells = malloc(sizeof(List*) * N * N); 

    for (i = 0; i < N * N; i++)
    {
        /* malloc is called inside NewList()*/
        cells[i] = newList(N); // << Note change here.
        for (j = 0; j < N; j++)
            addList(cells[i], j + 1);
    }
    return cells;
}

/* free */
for (i = 0; i < N * N;  i++)
{
    free(cells[i]->ini); // << and here
    /* line below causes CRASH */
    free(cells[i]); // << and here
}
free(cells);
```